# Missing Microsoft IoT Extension SDK in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows-iot

I've got Visual Studio Enterprise Update 1 installed and am trying to do some Raspberry Pi 2 development. I've installed the Windows 10 SDK. Most of the samples I see on the Internet say I need to add a project reference to Microsoft IoT Extension SDK. I do not see this extension listed. As a result, I can't use Windows.Devices.Gpio assembly (not found).

I've tried re-installing the SDK but to no avail. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you walked through this entire check-list on requirements? http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/GetStarted/SetUpVisualStudio.htm

Comment: @ThomasStringer Yes, everything in that list checked out. One thing I did notice was that when I tried to install Universal Windows App Development tools through the VS installer, it looked like it worked but going back into setup shows that the Win 10 SDK is not installed. So I downloaded that separately from Microsoft and installed external to VS, which also appeared to work. However, when I select modify VS installation it again shows the SDK as not installed (unchecked). I'm guessing this is my problem but not sure how to fix?

Comment: I eventually uninstalled/reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 and now the extension shows up correctly.

Comment: There is also Windows 10 IoT Core Project Templates package, one for Visual Studio 2015 and one for VS 2017 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MicrosoftIoT.WindowsIoTCoreProjectTemplates and see as well this setup guide with various links to materials about Windows 10 IoT development https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/getstarted/rpi3/sdcard/stable/getstartedstep1